# "QuotaExceededError" on Android App(IONIC) - When I'm trying to store a value in local storage (Ionic Storage)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

When I'm trying to set a normal value in Local Storage using [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).

It gives the following issue[image: It gives the following issue]

It works fine in ionic android applications on premium phones (Having high performance).

But on budget android phones, when that mobile has memory issue such as having less than a GB available memory space. Inserting the first value in local storage it throws "QuotaExceededError". Which disable my app to use its local storage on that particular phone.

How can I address this issue?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: Yes! wait giving the solution @HudsonCavazin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After days of searching, I got the solution!

You need to set the Ionic Storage default such as below in your `app.module.ts` under imports.

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
name: ‘__mydb’,
driverOrder: [‘sqlite’, ‘websql’, ‘indexeddb’]
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I set this and I also set IonicStorageModule, but it didn't work for me. any other solution?

Comment: late answer: remember to install the sqlite plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` (npm > 3.5.2)

Answer (score -2):

After days of searching, I got the solution!

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
name: ‘__mydb’,
driverOrder: [‘sqlite’, ‘websql’]
})
```

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

[Storage Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)